# Determine number of zeros using Rouché Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I am finding problem in evaluating the flowing function using Rouché's theorem.
I have looked out for examples but it lacks the explanation and steps to reach the required output.

I need to determine the number of zeros of the function f(y) = y^5+14y+1 for 1 < |y| < 2

I have understood that i need to break it into 2 parts.

If you could help me out.

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question [not an exact duplicate but I think you can figure it out from here]? [Find the number of zeroes of $p(z)=z^6+z^3+10z^2+4z+3$ inside the annulus $1&lt;|z|&lt;2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752697/find-the-number-of-zeroes-of-pz-z6z310z24z3-inside-the-annulus-1z)

Comment: Thank you. Am.looking into it. The thing is base on what do we decide on how to break the equation ?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please use MathJax when you ask questions. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference